# After processing request getting page cannot be displayed

Tags: jsp, jboss, struts, struts-1

In our application we have a page where we have three options, once we select any of the radio button and submit it will fetch all the email ids stored in a table based on selected option and validates the emails in LDAP updates another table witht he results from LSPA and returns the success message to the page.

For each option it takes different time to process. For one of the option it is taking less than 2 minutes and success message is getting displayed as expected but for the other two options the time taking to process is more than 3 minutes as the number of emails to be validated is more. In these two cases we are getting page cannot be displayed and we don't see any kind of errors in the logs or console.

we have increased the session time out to 10 minutes in web.xml and we have added LDAP timeout option with 20 minutes for testing. But still we are receiving the same issue. Suspecting the issue with browser and jboss server communication.

We are using jsp and struts 1.3 in this application. Is there any way we can fix this at application or server level.

Comment: Check your DB Queries that how long it takes to execute. If it's take more time optimize the queries too.

Comment: It seems impossible with struts 1.3, you need to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @Vinoth, We already did that. But problem is if the number of email ids to be validated from LDAP increases then the time to validate also will increase. That is also we need to handle. But not sure how to handle. In google we found the default timeout for IE is 2 mins. But we cannot change as we have to ask each and every user to change which is impossible. Any other solution is there